# Inconsistent standard input redirection behaviour with libuv

Tags: c, libuv

I am working on a small libuv-based program.  This program should read user-given text from standard input and provide results based off of the input.  Below is the source code for the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <uv.h>

static void
alloc_buffer(uv_handle_t *handle, size_t suggested_size, uv_buf_t *buf)
{
    static char buffer[1 << 16];
    *buf = uv_buf_init(buffer, 1 << 16);
}

static void
read_stdin(uv_stream_t *stream, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t* buf)
{
    printf("Read STDIN\n");
    if (nread < 0) {
        // stdin closed
        uv_read_stop(stream);
        return;
    }
    printf("Input length: %zu\n", nread);
    printf("Buffer length: %zu (%s)\n", buf->len, buf->base);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Initialize loop */
    uv_loop_t loop;
    uv_loop_init(&loop);

    /* Input */
    uv_tty_t input;
    uv_tty_init(&loop, &input, STDIN_FILENO, 1);
    uv_read_start((uv_stream_t *)&input, alloc_buffer, read_stdin);

    /* Run loop */
    uv_run(&loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    return 0;
}
```

The above program works fine after being compiled and invoked with no standard input redirection.  For example:

```
> ./test
hello world
Read STDIN
Input length: 12
Buffer length: 65536 (hello world
)
Read STDIN
>>> stdin closed
```

And piping the result of `echo` or some other process yields the correct result as well:

```
> echo "hello world" | ./test
Read STDIN
Input length: 12
Buffer length: 65536 (hello world
)
Read STDIN
>>> stdin closed
```

An issue arises when I try to redirect standard input from some regular file or  `/dev/null`:

```
> ./test < text.txt
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Below is the gdb backtrace of the crash:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6df2d67 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6df4118 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff79c6c90 in uv.io_poll () from /usr/lib/libuv.so.11
#3  0x00007ffff79ba64f in uv_run () from /usr/lib/libuv.so.11
#4  0x0000000000400b4b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe338) at main.c:40
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?  Am I using the libuv API incorrectly?

Comment: I wonder why the `echo` example works. The redirected stdin is certainly not a TTY. What does `uv_tty_init` return?

Comment: @user58697:  `uv_tty_init` returns `0` in all examples.  Additionally, `isatty` returns `1` for the first example and `0` for the rest, which isn't surprising.

Comment: Sounds like bug in libuv. I am not surprised at all. Please report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried running the failing program through **strace** and saw the following line right before the program was aborted:

```
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 0, {EPOLLIN, {u32=0, u64=0}}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

I did some further reading and it seems using epoll with a regular file descriptor simply does not work. In the first two of the original three tests, file descriptor 0 (standard input) was not a regular file. In the last test, the shell would have closed and replaced file descriptor 0 with the input file `text.txt`.

I will most likely have to use the libuv library function [`uv_guess_handle`](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/blob/master/include/uv.h#L1148), which can be used to determine the type of the `STDIN_FILENO` file descriptor:

> ```
> /*
> * Used to detect what type of stream should be used with a given file
> * descriptor. Usually this will be used during initialization to guess the
> * type of the stdio streams.
> * For isatty() functionality use this function and test for UV_TTY.
> */
> UV_EXTERN uv_handle_type uv_guess_handle(uv_file file);
> ```